# Hibernate native query method

Tags: java, jquery, spring, hibernate, jpa

So, I am doing an assignment where I have a 2 Entities - `User` `and Car` with a OneToMany relationship respectively.

Therefore `User` will posses a List of `Cars`.

I need to implement a controller method, which will be displaying all the cars that user posses by UserId(which is a foreign key for Car entity)

Method is: `[GET] - /users/{id}/cars`

Right now If I am simply seleting all users I am getting raw JSON smth like that:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Taavet Prulskih",
  "cars":[{
    "Id":"1",
    "make":"BMW",
    "model":"760",
    "numberplate":"123FFF"
  },
  {
    "Id":"2",
    "make":"Opel",
    "model":"Astra",
    "numberplate":"789BFX"
  }]
}
```

But I don't want to have a data about User, because it's not necessary as I am already specifing in get request that I am selecting a certain user. So I wan't to have only the list of cars that certain user posses.

The JSON output that I am looking for is:

```
{  
   "Id":"1",
   "make":"BMW",
   "model":"760",
   "numberplate":"123FFF"
},
{  
   "Id":"2",
   "make":"Opel",
   "model":"Astra",
   "numberplate":"789BFX"
}
```

ATM I have a CarRepository which extends JpaRepository with a method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Cars c where c.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Car> findByUserId(@Param("id") Long id);
```

But for some reason I am getting a "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present" exception. When trying to use findByUserId Query method.

Controller part that doesnt work:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}/cars")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> getAllCarsByUserId(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(carRepository.findByUserId(id).get());
    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Cars c where c.user_id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Car> findByUserId(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

Could you be so cool to help me to geet done with that issue?

Thank You in advance! :)

Comment: Could you please add the JSON output that you want to obtain in your controller?

Comment: Just a moment, I will edit the post and put it in the original quetion, not in the comment below.

Comment: Your JSON output is not valid, I thing you need to add **[** at the begging and **]** at the end, isn't it?

Comment: Should be valid, I used a json vslidator for that. But that isn't the question. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my understanding of what you are looking for:

**Repositoy**

```java
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM T_CARS c where c.USER_ID = :id", nativeQuery = true)
  Collection<Car> findByUserId(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

**Controller**

```java
class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private CarRepository carRepository;

  @GetMapping("/users/{id}/cars")
  public ResponseEntity<Collection<Car>> getAllCarsByUserId(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(carRepository.findByUserId(id));
  }

}
```

I hope that it works for you :)

Comment: But when I am using List instead of optional it gives me a redline conflict :(

Comment: Could you please test with `Collection<Car>`

Comment: You should, by the way, add the necessary import statement: `import java.util.Collection;`

Comment: Same issue.
Btw my method looks like that:
@GetMapping("/users/{id}/cars")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> getAllCarsByUserId(@PathVariable("id") Long id)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(carRepository.findByUserId(id).get());
    }

Comment: Could you please add in your question the code of your controller and your repository (the methods that don't work properly) to understand what's going on?

Comment: Yeah I added both Repository and controller part to the main question part :)

Comment: You are right, my answer was too much. I have updated ;) Can you tell me if this what you are looking for or not?

Comment: For some reason I am getting an empty array :( Even tho I almost literally copy pasted yoru code. (Copied controller part just to make sure, copied repository native query part)

Comment: Could you check the users and cars you have in the database

Comment: I am checking it every time before trying to use that method. Everytime before hitting /users/1/cars URL I am hitting /users/1 URL to see if it has all the data saved.

Comment: Is there any exception in the output of jour application?

Comment: Nope everything works fine, besides that it returns an empty array no matter which {id} i put into the /users/{id}/cars, it even return empty array of {id} that is not saved to the database.

Comment: Could you please check the output of this native query executed directly in your database : `select * from CARS c where c.user_id = 1`

Comment: Buddy it's okay, I have fixed it :) Thank you SO MUCH for this help (:
Since I copied your native query just to check I had a table name "Cars" in native query, while my db table is "Car" and "Cars" was empty while "Car" returns a non-empty array now.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help ;) could you please mark the answer if this one was what you are looking for ;)

Comment: Just press the arrow to vote? Or is there anything besides that?

Comment: In fact, in stackoverflow, we can do two things: we can vote and we can accept an answer. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) will help you

Comment: Done buddy 8)  :P

Comment: glad I was able to help, have a nice day ;)